# Ng-model did't show updated value until click somewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, angular-ngmodel

All I want to do is to display the value of a ngModel, a variable defined in my controller. But the value didn't change to the correct value until I click somewhere else on the page or click the update button again. Although it does change to the correct value in the console.

My themeLayout.html file

```
<div class="theme-body" ng-controller="ThemeController as theme">
  <select ng-model="theme.selectedTheme" ng-change="theme.getThemeDetails(theme.selectedTheme)">
    <option ng-repeat="option in theme.themePacks">{{option.title}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="appLogo">App Logo</label>
    <div>
      <img ng-src="{{theme.currentThemeImageUrl}}" alt="Description" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appLogo" ng-model="theme.currentThemeImageUrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my theme controller

```
    export default class ThemeController {
      constructor($log, ApiService, $scope, $state, $window) {
        'ngInject';
        this.s3 = new this.AWS.S3();
        this.selectedTheme = '';
        this.currentThemeId = '';
        this.currentS3ThemeOption = {};
        this.currentS3ThemeOptionToUpload = {};
        this.currentThemeImageUrl = '';
      }
      getThemeDetails(theme) {
        this.$log.log(`get theme details function been called`, theme);
        const obj = this;
        for(let item of this.themePacks) {
          if (theme === item.title) {
            this.currentThemeId = item.themeId;
          }
        }
        this.s3.getObject({
        Bucket: `improd-image-pipeline`,
        Key: `remoteUX/qa/${obj.currentThemeId}.json`,
        }, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            obj.$log.log(err);
          } else {
            obj.currentS3ThemeOption = JSON.parse(data.Body);
            obj.currentS3ThemeOptionToUpload = obj.currentS3ThemeOption;
            for (const prop in obj.currentS3ThemeOption.colors) {
              obj[prop] = obj.getColors(obj.currentS3ThemeOption.colors[prop]);
            }
            obj.currentThemeImageUrl = obj.currentS3ThemeOption.layout.titleImageUrl;
            obj.$log.log(`We should have upadted theme opion now`, obj.currentS3ThemeOption, obj.currentThemeImageUrl);
          }
     });
       this.$log.log(obj.currentS3ThemeOption, this.currentS3ThemeOption);
     }
}
```

This is when I click the fox option in the selection, it read the data and stroe it into the currentSeThemeOption.
[image]

As you can see from the console, it also print of the value 
[image]

What I am thingking is that might the 'this' and obj is causing the problem.

After I did add $scope.apply() function as he suggested, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Initialize the variable from the start of controller __OR__ use `$apply` to take change in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your model inside a `scope.$apply()` call:

```
getThemeDetails(theme) {
  this.$log.log(`get theme details function been called`, theme);
  const obj = this;
  for(let item of this.themePacks) {
    if (theme === item.title) {
      this.currentThemeId = item.themeId;
    }
  }
  this.s3.getObject({
  Bucket: `improd-image-pipeline`,
  Key: `remoteUX/qa/${obj.currentThemeId}.json`,
  }, (err, data) =>
    scope.$apply(() => {
    if (err) {
      obj.$log.log(err);
    } else {
      obj.currentS3ThemeOption = JSON.parse(data.Body);
      obj.currentS3ThemeOptionToUpload = obj.currentS3ThemeOption;
      for (const prop in obj.currentS3ThemeOption.colors) {
        obj[prop] = obj.getColors(obj.currentS3ThemeOption.colors[prop]);
      }
      obj.currentThemeImageUrl = obj.currentS3ThemeOption.layout.titleImageUrl;
      obj.$log.log(`We should have upadted theme opion now`, obj.currentS3ThemeOption, obj.currentThemeImageUrl);
    }
  })
);
  this.$log.log(obj.currentS3ThemeOption, this.currentS3ThemeOption);
}
```

Comment: @bchemy, Thanks, but what does this scope.$apply() do and why my code isn't working?

Comment: `scope.$apply` tells Angular that something on the scope may have changed. Usually Angular does this for you, but sometimes (eg. when triggering a fn from outside of Angular) you have to do it manually. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Answer (score 2):

Once you have assigned a $scope object into the ng-model object. then you just put

```
$scope.$apply();
```

so that it will bind properly with UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's the problem of digest cycle the digest cycle in triggered in only in four conditions

event (i.e your click),
http request,
change in input,
Timers with callbacks ($timeout etc.),